# Generic integer casting in swift

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to transform the following sentences:

```
infix operator <*> {}

public func <*> (left: Int64, right: Int16) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8( (left & Int64((1 << right))) >> Int64(right) )
}

public func <*> (left: Int32, right: Int16) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8( (left & Int32((1 << right))) >> Int32(right) )
}
```

by only one generic function similar to:

```
public func <*> <T: IntegerType>(left: T, right: Int8) -> Bit {
    return UInt8( (left & T((1 << right))) >> T(right) )
}
```

The problem is that I'm not able to construct or cast `1 << right` or `right` to `T`:

`Overloads for 'T' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (integerLiteral: Self.IntegerLiteralType), (_builtinIntegerLiteral: _MaxBuiltinIntegerType)`

Is there any way to express this using generics ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `Integer`-related protocols are due to be reworked in Swift 3 (though they are not ready for Preview 1).

Right now, you can't do what you're trying to do because `IntegerType` does not expose a way to convert from/to other integer types, as you're trying to do with `T((1 << right))`. If you specialized on `SignedIntegerType` and `UnsignedIntegerType` instead, you'll be able to use the `T(_: IntMax)` and `T(_: UIntMax)` initializers, respectively, to create integers.

My understanding is that your functions return whether a bit is set on an integer. I don't have access to a Swift compiler here but I think that this would work:

```
func <*> <T: IntegerType>(left: T, right: T) -> T {
    return left >> right & 1
}
```

**EDIT**: The `<<` and `>>` operators are currently not part of any protocol, which will make it very painful to use them in generics. The above example doesn't work.

Comment: If I choose `UnsignedIntegerType`for example, I have a new error:  `Cannot convert value of type 'Int8' to expected argument type 'UInt64'`

Comment: As I wrote, if you choose `UnsignedIntegerType`, you have access to an initializer that expects a `UIntMax` value. You need to convert that `Int8` to a `UIntMax`.